# Prune JSON tree with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, tree, pruning

I am working with JavaScript the JSON structure shown below.  I have a requirement to create a pruned version of the tree such that the user can select  a particular attribute value and the new tree would consist of all nodes with that value and any nodes who have that value as a descendent.  For example if the user selects the attribute ‘can move’ the new tree should contain nodes 0, 4, 2, 8, 1, 14, 12 and 17.   Nodes 4, 8, 14 and 17 have the attribute and nodes 0, 2, 1 and 12 have the attribute in one of their descendants.  Any help appreciated

```
var treeData = {
    "Node": 0,
    "attributes": ["needs water to live"],
    "objects": ["corn", "bean", "dog", "reed", "water weeds", "frog", "bream", "fish leech"],
    "own_objects": [],
    "ObjectCount": "8 | 100%",

    "children": [{
        "Node": 4,
        "attributes": ["can move"],
        "objects": ["fish leech", "dog", "frog", "bream"],
        "own_objects": ["fish leech"],
        "ObjectCount": "4 | 50%",

        "children": [{
            "Node": 5,
            "attributes": ["has limbs"],
            "objects": ["bream", "frog", "dog"],
            "own_objects": ["bream", "frog", "dog"],
            "ObjectCount": "3 | 37%"
        }]
    }, {
        "Node": 3,
        "attributes": ["needs chlorophyll"],
        "objects": ["bean", "corn", "reed", "water weeds"],
        "own_objects": ["bean"],
        "ObjectCount": "4 | 50%",

        "children": [{
            "Node": 6,
            "attributes": ["monocotyledon"],
            "objects": ["water weeds", "reed", "corn"],
            "own_objects": ["water weeds", "reed", "corn"],
            "ObjectCount": "3 | 37%"
        }]
    }, {
        "Node": 2,
        "attributes": ["lives on land"],
        "objects": ["dog", "frog", "corn", "bean", "reed"],
        "own_objects": [],
        "ObjectCount": "5 | 62%",

        "children": [{
            "Node": 8,
            "attributes": ["can move", "has limbs"],
            "objects": ["frog", "dog"],
            "own_objects": ["frog"],
            "ObjectCount": "2 | 25%",

            "children": [{
                "Node": 9,
                "attributes": ["breast feeds"],
                "objects": ["dog"],
                "own_objects": ["dog"],
                "ObjectCount": "1 | 12%"
            }]
        }, {
            "Node": 7,
            "attributes": ["needs chlorophyll"],
            "objects": ["corn", "reed", "bean"],
            "own_objects": [],
            "ObjectCount": "3 | 37%",

            "children": [{
                "Node": 11,
                "attributes": ["monocotyledon"],
                "objects": ["reed", "corn"],
                "own_objects": ["reed", "corn"],
                "ObjectCount": "2 | 25%"
            }, {
                "Node": 10,
                "attributes": ["dicotyledon"],
                "objects": ["bean"],
                "own_objects": ["bean"],
                "ObjectCount": "1 | 12%"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "Node": 1,
        "attributes": ["lives in water"],
        "objects": ["bream", "fish leech", "water weeds", "reed", "frog"],
        "own_objects": [],
        "ObjectCount": "5 | 62%",

        "children": [{
            "Node": 14,
            "attributes": ["can move"],
            "objects": ["fish leech", "frog", "bream"],
            "own_objects": ["fish leech"],
            "ObjectCount": "3 | 37%",

            "children": [{
                "Node": 15,
                "attributes": ["has limbs"],
                "objects": ["bream", "frog"],
                "own_objects": ["bream", "frog"],
                "ObjectCount": "2 | 25%"
            }]
        }, {
            "Node": 13,
            "attributes": ["needs chlorophyll", "monocotyledon"],
            "objects": ["water weeds", "reed"],
            "own_objects": ["water weeds", "reed"],
            "ObjectCount": "2 | 25%"
        }, {
            "Node": 12,
            "attributes": ["lives on land"],
            "objects": ["frog", "reed"],
            "own_objects": [],
            "ObjectCount": "2 | 25%",

            "children": [{
                "Node": 17,
                "attributes": ["can move", "has limbs"],
                "objects": ["frog"],
                "own_objects": ["frog"],
                "ObjectCount": "1 | 12%"
            }, {
                "Node": 16,
                "attributes": ["needs chlorophyll", "monocotyledon"],
                "objects": ["reed"],
                "own_objects": ["reed"],
                "ObjectCount": "1 | 12%"
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  I have found a solution so I post it here in case it is useful to anyone else, although I guess it is a very specific requirement.

```
 function hasAttributeOrDescendantAttribute(tree) {
    if (tree.attributes) {
        if (tree.attributes.some(attr => attr == $("#attributeDropdown option:selected").text() ))
            return true;
    }

    if (tree.children) {
        if (tree.children.some(hasAttributeOrDescendantAttribute)) return true;

    }
    return false;
}

function prune(tree, result) {

    result.Node = tree.Node;
    result.attributes = tree.attributes;
    result.objects = tree.objects;
    result.ObjectCount = tree.ObjectCount;
    result.own_objects = tree.own_objects;

    if (tree.children) {

        result.children = [];

        for (child of tree.children) {

            if (hasAttributeOrDescendantAttribute(child)) {
                result.children.push({});
                prune(child, result.children[result.children.length - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

treeData = prune(treeData, {});
```